# Add arrow next to a reference to get back to read where you left?

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

In Wikipedia there's this small arrow next to each reference, which will bring you to the spot where this was used. I could imagine that is very much imaginable with LaTeX, but I don't actually know what it's called and what to search for. Has anyone experienced with this before? (Note: we are using the ieee format)

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The term you're looking for is a back-reference.¹ This is supported out of the box with the `hyperref` package. Just add

```
\usepackage[pagebackref]{hyperref}
```

By default, it will give a list of pages with the references on them (which makes sense since you will often have multiple references to the same citation (note, for example, item 7 in your screenshot which has 7 ^ <sup>*a b c*</sup> to reflect multiple citations. The formatting, which has the page numbers as hyperlinks at the end of the bibliography entry can be refined using some command redefinitions as described in `texdoc hyperref` (section 5.26) although moving those links to the beginning of the bibliography entry wouldn't be possible without some significant surgery on the code of the class.

---

1. As [Mac B, Kid Spy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/133814359X)² would say, “good name.“
2. My kids and I read this series over the course of the pandemic lockdown. Fun books for those of you with kids ages 6–12.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. Where exactly can I add "texdoc hyperref"? In the usepackage line or after?

Comment: @johnny_1010 You would run this command from your command line or shell or something like that. `texdoc` will search its database of packages or tools documentation and open the most relevant documentation in an associated viewer.

Comment: @johnny_1010 In case of not having a `texdoc` program, you can also go to https://texdoc.org or search the package  in CTAN to see the manual.